# Why border-radius:none will be overwritten by border-radius:0 5px 0 0?

Tags: css, darkmode

I want to add a dark style to a class. However, the border-radius:none doesn't work. But if I change it to border-raidus: 0 0 0 0; it works.

[image]

(not working)

[image]

(working)

Why?

Comment: because as you can see, it's invalid

Comment: Change it to border-radius:0;

Answer (score 0):

As KK correctly mentions, the default value for the CSS border-radius property is 0. 'none' is not an allowed value.

See here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

When used like below, it sets the radius for all four areas (top, bottom, left, right):
Border-radius:0

When used like in your example, it is CSS shorthand for specifying each area individually.